# Como enviar Json con un script de python y recibirlo en un Script de Arduino

Tags: python, json, arduino, pyserial

Es posible enviar un json de un script de Python a un script de Arduino ?
tengo esta función que recibe un diccionario y lo convierto a json y lo mando con la función write, pero no se como recibirlo desde Arduino, alguien tendrá algún ejemplo ?

```
import serial
import json

def f_comunicacion(dato):
    arduino = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)

    dato_json = json.dumps(dato)
    print(f"Dato: {type(dato)}\nDato Json: {type(dato_json)}")

    arduino.write(f"{dato_json}".encode())
```

---

Edit:

Esto funciona para mi, pero aun no entiendo algunos puntos.

```
// Por que char y el asterisco, y por que no un String ? se supone que 
   desde Python se envía como String o es lo que yo entendi.
char* colorRojo; 
char* colorVerde;
char* colorAzul;

String input;
// Por que 64 ?, es el espacio en memoria que ocupa ?
StaticJsonDocument<64> doc;
```

---

Código completo:

```
char* colorRojo;
char* colorVerde;
char* colorAzul;

String input;
StaticJsonDocument<64> doc;

void loop() {
 if (Serial.available()) {
   input = Serial.readString(); // Leemos el valor recibido por el monitor serial
   DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, input); // Deserializamos

 if (error) {
   Serial.print("Error de deserializacion");
   Serial.println(error.f_str());
   return;
 }

 colorRojo = doc["rojo"]; 
 colorVerde = doc["verde"];
 colorAzul = doc["azul"]; 
 
 lcd.clear();
 lcd.setCursor(0, 0);// Fila, columna;
 lcd.print("R: " + String(colorRojo)); 

 lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
 lcd.print("G: " + String(colorVerde)); 

 lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
 lcd.print("A: " + String(colorAzul));

 }

 analogWrite(ledRojo, String(colorRojo).toInt());
 analogWrite(ledVerde, String(colorVerde).toInt());
 analogWrite(ledAzul, String(colorAzul).toInt());
 }
```

Comment: El Arduino usará la puerta serial, la misma que usa Serial Monitor. Si tu código sabe leer desde la puerta serial, puede leer desde el PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo de juguete de comunicación Arduino - PC. Una aplicación real tendrá manejo de errores y protocolos mejor definidos que los aquí presentados. Esto es sólo un punto de partida.

#### Arduino

Este es un sencillo sketch Arduino que escucha en la puerta serial y responde lo mismo que recibe, además de parpadear el LED incluido por cada caracter recibido.

```
/*
 * Echo Server
 * 
 * Escucha en la puerta serial y responde lo mismo que recibe
 */
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char in_byte = Serial.read();
    Serial.write(in_byte);    
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
  }
}
```

Nota importante: Hay que leer la puerta serial caracter a caracter. Si usas `readString`, el programa se quedará detenido esperando hasta recibir un '\n' o hasta time-out. Not good.

La manera correcta es preguntar primero si hay caracteres en el buffer de entrada y luego leerlos. Eso garantiza que la llamada no bloqueara, y que cada ejecución de `loop()` será corta.

#### Python

```
def f_comunicacion(dato):
    arduino = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1", 9600, timeout=.5)

    dato_json = json.dumps(dato).encode()
    arduino.write(dato_json)
    while True:
        car = arduino.read(1).decode()
        if len(car):
            print(car, end="")
        else:
            break
```

Para mandar la información al Arduino basta con hacer un `write()`. Luego de enviar el json, entramos en un ciclo leyendo caracter a caracter lo que Arduino responde e imprimiendolo en pantalla.

Parece no haber una manera simple de preguntar si hay algo para leer en el buffer de entrada; opte por colocar un timeout de 0.5 segundos a la lectura.

#### Demo

```
dato = dict(manual="on", timer="off", val=1, texto="""
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890
""")

f_comunicacion(dato)
```

produce:

```
{"manual": "on", "timer": "off", "val": 1, "texto": "\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\nLorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890 Lorem Sump 1234567890\n"}
Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Transmisión de valores numéricos

Los valores numéricos deben ser formateados como string antes de enviarlos por la puerta serial, y reconvertido a entero/punto flotante del lado receptor. En el ejemplo, `json.dumps` se encarga de convertir todo a string.

Es posible enviar valores binarios por la puerta serial, pero eso haría la aplicación dependiente de la arquitectura, amen de las complicaciones para convertir apropiadamente de una arquitectura a otra.

Comment: Me dejaste muy claro muchas cosas.